# dynamic closure functions for a game in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

Im working on a simple html/javascript multiplication game, in which I have a multiplication table with some inputs that represet the results of the products. in that game, you need to answer as fast as you can on as many questions as you can. to make it easy on the players, ive assign an event to the enter key to move to the next input when it is pressed.

[image: multiplication table game]

Here is the javascript code for highlighting the rows and the enter key event:

```
for (var i=0; i<boardInputArray.length; i++) {
    boardInputArray[i].onkeydown = (function(nextBox) {
        return function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                if(nextBox==boardInputArray.length) {boardInputArray[0].focus();boardInputArray[0].select();}
                else {boardInputArray[nextBox].focus();boardInputArray[nextBox].select();}
                var gameCompleted = true;
                for(var c=0;c<boardInputArray.length;c++) {
                    if(boardInputArray[c].value == '') {gameCompleted = false;}
                }
                if(gameCompleted) validateGame();
            }
        }
    })(i+1);
}
```

I dont want to post the entire code here, because it is very long. If you would like to see the game in action, go to: 
http://www.webdesk.co.il/articles/javascript/multiplication-table-game.php

Here's the problem: I would like that each time the Enter key is pressed, it will check if the following input is empty or not. in case its not empty - skip to the next one and so on until it finds an empty input. That way, the player can go back to the question he didnt answer and not go through all the ones he did answer. makes sense?

Comment: It makes sense... but only after I played the game once.

Comment: Note to players: Click התחל משחק חדש to start the game.

Comment: Thanks @JohnPick, I will add that to the game instructions. By the way, that means "Start a new game" in hebrew...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably improve this code, but it does take care of moving to the next empty box.

```
for (var i=0; i<boardInputArray.length; i++) {
    boardInputArray[i].onkeydown = (function(currentBox) {
        return function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                var gameCompleted = true;
                if(boardInputArray[currentBox].value == '')
                    gameCompleted = false;
                for (
                        var c = (currentBox + 1) % boardInputArray.length;
                        c != currentBox;
                        c = (c + 1) % boardInputArray.length
                    )
                {
                    if(boardInputArray[c].value == '')
                    {
                        gameCompleted = false;
                        boardInputArray[c].focus();
                        boardInputArray[c].select();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(gameCompleted) validateGame();
            }
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Notes:

- I've made the anonymous function a function of currentBox instead of nextBox (`i` instead of `i + 1`).
- The loop goes through all the boxes except the current box, by starting at the next box, wrapping around and ending at the previous box or when it encounters a blank box.

Comment: This does take care of validating the game only when all the inputs are filled, but it doesent skip them...